# Database busy during one thread is writing in one table and other thread accessing the data from other table

Tags: ios, fmdb

I am inserting lot of data in some tables in background thread.During inserting if app accessing the data from other table I got an Database busy error.I am using FMDatabase.
how to solve these issue?

Answer (score 1):

Use FMDatabaseQueue, it's meant for situations like this.